# How to plan IP when having two pair?

Tags: nlhe, microstakes

I was playing the following game in NL2 6-max (max buy-in: 50BB):

**Preflop:**

MP: (50BB) limps

CO: Hero (64BB): A♠2♥ raises **4BB**

SB: (175BB)  calls

MP folds

**Flop (10BB)**:

A♥Q♠2⋄

SB bets 5BB

Hero raises to 20BB

SB goes all in

Hero calls

**Showdown spoiler:**

> SB showed AQ and took the pot

Comment: What is IP?  One of those hand when you look back you think yes I could have gotten away but it is hard to release 2 pair.

Comment: Did you have any reads/history with this opponent?

Comment: IP = In Position?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really like the raise on the flop.  The range of hands that the opponent has here is somewhat limited.  A set is unlikely since AA and QQ would often re-raise, you hold one of the A's and one of the 2's, and a good portion of players would check with a flopped set here.  It's possible that they have some low pocket pair or maybe a Q (KQ,QJ,Q10) and don't want to check and face a bet and there's always the chance of a bluff.  But there are no good draws and the most likely holding by far is a paired ace in which case you're only worried about AQ or the 3 outs that they have (well the board could pair also which would be bad for you).

Given their range, you're probably ahead but raising on the flop doesn't do much to get value for you.  Most of the range that you beat can safely fold and most turn cards are safe for you.  You're probably ahead so I'd give them the opportunity to bet again on the turn or else if they check then you can bet there.  In the case that you're behind, there's the benefit that the pot size stays more manageable.

Pretty much any raise you make on the flop will commit you to the pot--but even though your hand is strong, it's not a favorite against the range of hands that he'd go all in with so you'd don't necessarily want to get it all in.  You probably have to make the call though because you only need 30% equity and he could have AK or some crazy bluff or you could have a couple outs--but you shouldn't be wanting to get it all in here because you're probably a dog in that case.  Even if the opponent only calls your raise, he's kind of committing himself to the pot--but the very best case scenario is that he's calling your raise with something like AJ.  Most of the time though, your raise is either scaring away worse hands or inviting better hands to re-raise.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what you mean by IP?

A2 unsuited from CO is marginal.

This would really depend on if you had been abusing the blinds from the CO and you think SB is just making a stand.

On the flop SB led out with 1/2 pot bet rather than check to the preflop aggressor.  To me that looks like:

- a pair of queens or weak ace wanting to find out if they are good
- on big hand and building a pot
- it is not a stab at the pot hoping for you to fold or they would have
  bet more

You bet 20 into the pot bringing it to 35.  SB is getting 35 : 15 to call.
What are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to get a single pair to call for value?  20 is 1/3 of your stack on the flop - you are pot committed with that bet.

SB pushes so you are getting 90 : 40 to call
What can you beat?

- single pair

What can you loose to?

- AQ
  yes villain would have played it that way
- AA
  you hold and Ace so not likely and they would slow play that
  and probably would have raised preflop
- QQ
  not likely as they would slow play that
  and probably would have raised preflop
- Lone Ace
  Even a lone ace will beat you 17% of the time as even a paired board counterfeits your pair of 2.

Without a read on them I guess you need to call.  You are basically pot committed. You are probably beat but you are getting over 2 : 1. If you fold you are down to 40 bb but 40 bb is still playable.

Back to why raise the flop. If you are ahead then you will likely stay ahead as there are no draws on the board.  If the plan is to get their chips then let them bet into you.  You have position so you can always bet if they check.  If they then bet the pot on the turn which they likely would then you would have decision to make.

Comment: IP = In Position, OOP = Out of Position

Answer (score 1):

Raising a donkbet is probably best but you kinda pot-commited yourself (1/3 of your stack) with the 20bb.

If you were not willing to pot-commit yourself, raising to something like 15bb is best to me, you could laydown easier then.

Checking his stats deeper is needed here, specifically how much $ he wins in Showdown (W$SD in pokertracker), you can't get a straight answer here without digging your opponent.

There are some opponents that never donks, having like a *3/231 (1%)* of this stat in pokertracker. You have to find how frequently they do this play as well.